# JSON.stringify(array) returns []

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to stringify multiple arrays, but unsuccessfully

```
var arr=new Array();
arr['do']='smth';
arr['asd']=[];
arr['asd']['dsa']='alo';
var string=JSON.stringify(arr)
console.log(arr);
console.log(string);
```

`JSON.stringify` returns []

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating an array, and use it as if it was a json object. You should create an object if you need an object.

```
var obj={};
obj['do']='smth';
obj['asd']=[];
obj['asd']['dsa']='alo';
var string=JSON.stringify(obj)
console.log(obj);
console.log(string);
```

Comment: You just suggested he name an object arr. downvote for just making it even more confusing for him.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use named keys in javascript, you should use an [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) as the JSON serializer ignores any named keys in arrays. A rule of thumb is that you should use arrays for `[0]`, `[1]` etc., but objects for `['foo']`, `['bar']` etc.

```
var obj = {
    'do': 'smth',
    'asd': {
        'dsa': 'alo'
    }
};

console.log( JSON.stringify(obj) );
//{"do":"smth","asd":{"dsa":"alo"}}
```

Comment: Did you mean named keys don't exist in arrays?

Comment: The keys *do* exist, but they're ignored by the JSON serializer.

Comment: @Pointy You're right - I changed my description a bit. It seems that Chrome's own console can't even output the variable right (run OP's code - type `arr` and you get nothing, but `console.log(arr)` does.)

Answer (score 1):

Use an object:

```
var object = {};
object['do']='smth';
object['asd']=[];
object['asd']['dsa']='alo';
var string=JSON.stringify(object)
console.log(object);
console.log(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot give the elements in an array names, they have their indizes as names. So if you would like to give them names use an JS-Object otherwise use the indizies in the definition as follows:

```
arr[0]='smth';
arr[1]=[];
arr[1][0]='alo';
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that JSON stands for javascript object notation , you should have  objects with the  required properties instead you are creating an array so  replace your arrays with {} and add to this